# Asterisk extension, conditional execution?

Tags: asterisk

I have an this extension in file /etc/asterisk/extensions_custom.conf:

```
    exten => _XXXX,1,NoOp("-- from internal custom --")
    exten => _XXXX,n,Set(CURL_RESULT=${CURL(https://your.domain.com/sip_webhook?callid=${EXTEN}&sourceid=${CALLERID(num)})})
    exten => _XXXX,n,Wait(3)
    exten => _XXXX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60)
    exten => _XXXX,n,Hangup()
```

The second line sends a request to a webhook in my server and stores the response in CURL_RESULT

I want to execute **Dial** only if **CURL_RESULT** was successful is there any way to achieve conditional execution of an extension?
something like:

```
if(CURL_RESULT=="OK")
exten => _XXXX,n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60)
else
exten => _XXXX,n,Hangup()
```

Comment: The point in the question is to know If what I want to do is possible, and if yes, I would invest time doing research, but if someone would tell me it is not possible then it is not worth it to go deeper into Asterisk and I will move to another Solution.

Comment: Asterisk dialplan is full grammatic. You can do any task using dialplan only(maybe not as affective as using any other language, but still can)

Comment: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+16+Application_GotoIf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as arheops indicated, this is actually a common built-in concept in the dialplan: conditional executing and conditional branching.

There are a lot of ways you could this - to give you some ideas:

#1: Conditional execute if true

```
exten => _XXXX,1,ExecIf($["${CURL_RESULT}" = "OK" ]?Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60))
   same => n,Hangup()
```

#2: Conditional branch if false

```
exten => _XXXX,1,GotoIf($["${CURL_RESULT}" != "OK" ]?exit)
   same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60)
   same => n(exit),Hangup()
```

#3: Conditional branch if true/false:

```
exten => _XXXX,1,GotoIf($["${CURL_RESULT}" = "OK" ]?dial:exit)
   same => n(dial),Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60)
   same => n(exit),Hangup()
```

That last example doesn't add anything in this case, but providing a true and false label is often useful.

If you want a *true* If/Else application in Asterisk, that works similar to in conventional programming languages, you can use the If module: <s>https://github.com/InterLinked1/phreakscript/blob/master/apps/app_if.c</s> (this has since been merged into Asterisk, you don't need to patch separately).

It's not currently included in mainline Asterisk so you'd need to drop that into your source, compile, and reinstall.

With that, you could do something like:

```
   same => n,If($["${CURL_RESULT}" = "OK" ])
       same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN},60)
       same => n,NoOp(${DIALSTATUS})
   same => n,Else()
       same => n,Playback(goodbye) ; do something else
   same => n,EndIf()
   same => n,Hangup() ; something after both
```

Each type of conditional syntax tends to work slightly nicer than some of the others in particular circumstances.